# Is it possible to load JQuery and its different plugins from Chrome JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, textarea, hotkeys

I would like to make a JavaScript function which enable the following: bind hotkeys for pasting different texts to textareas. When I use dating sites I got numerous messages, and I answer them with only 5-6 different sentences and their small variations. Would be helpful to bind those sentences to different key combinations for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc, and pasting them with those hotkeys to the current / focused textareas. For these I want to use JQuery and its plugin that makes it possible to bind hotkeys to javascript functions.

Comment: Yes. that is possible. you want to create and append a script tag to the page.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the browser extention [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for firefox or [tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for chrome. This extension will allow you to   create a custom script and only run it on specific URIs.